13:16 16% System log PowerManagerService(1365): UserActivityStateListenerState: 1 10-04 13:14:05.917 I/ Gesture): obtain mCurrentDownEvent. id:
dispatchInputEvent:337s happening here
Just need some clarification on this data
I am concerned and very new with this ter.inogy when ot comes to System.s I am looking for so
E clarification and direction,  where do I go from here,

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
